# How to register AutoMapper profiles when using class libraries?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, asp.net-core-webapi

So, I have a project with the following structure,

-- My-Project 
      -- Infrastructure-Layer 
      ---- InfraMappingProfiles.cs (AutoMapper Mapping Profiles) 
      ---- DI.cs (this is an extension method that calls `services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());`) 
      --- Application-Layer 
      ---- ApplicationMappingProfiles.cs (AutoMapper Mapping Profiles) 
      ---- DI.cs (this is an extension method that calls `services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());`)
      --- Common-Layer 
      ---- CommonMappingProfiles.cs (AutoMapper Mapping Profiles) 
      ---- DI.cs (this is an extension method that calls `services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());`) 
      --- Api-Layer 
      ---- ApiMappingProfiles.cs (AutoMapper Mapping Profiles) 
      ---- DI.cs (this is an extension method that calls `services.AddLayers() // register IServiceCollection from all layers`)

So, for some reason, AutoMapper only picks up one registration from the above. How can register all mapping profiles from the above layers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get all assemblies in the current domain. `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` is only going to return the main assembly. To scan all assemblies in the domain you would use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`. You should be able to pass that to `IServiceCollection.AddAutoMapper(...)`:

`services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());`

Comment: Hi @matt-u, Thank you for your post. I have already tried this, but for some reason the profiles are not being picked up by AddAutoMapper() method.

Comment: In this case the order likely matters: If you have not yet invoked any code from the ‘other assembly’ by the time you call CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies(), the other assembly won’t yet be loaded into the AppDomain.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems AddAutoMapper() method can be used only once. So, I had to add the profiles manually to the MapperConfiguration. Then register an instance of a mapper within an `IServiceCollection` using that configuration (see example below),

```
MapperConfiguration mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(mapperConfig => {
   mapperConfig.AddProfile<ExampleMapProfile>();
});

services.AddSingleton(mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper());
```

Comment: Strange. Thanks for sharing the solution. I have multiple Mapping Profiles in separate projects all the time, and the assembly scanning I suggested always works. Glad you fixed it.